# SCSS file-watcher encoding issue

Tags: css, sass, file-watcher

I have been using a SASS/SCSS file-watcher in my ide for quite a while now and for the past few days I have been having issues with the encoding. At the moment I work with another developer on a software and we're using a git system to handle the files.
A few days ago I pulled an update from git and sice then there seems to be something wrong with the encoding from the scss to css files.
For example:
When the file-watcher compiles the font-awesome scss files to css it changes the output from:

```
.fa-angle-left:before {
    content: "\f104";
}
```

to:

```
.fa-angle-left:before {
    content: "";
}
```

I have tried to change the encoding of the files but it doesn't seem to do anything. Does anybody have an idea on how I can fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: Can you add a little context to that value and what you're using it for?

Comment: @disinfor We're using the file-watcher to compile the font-awesome-scss-files to regular scss files. After compiling the scss files the regular css-code now looks very different. I have just edited the code within my question hoping that this will give a better example of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the content of the class to something like this:

```
.fa-angle-left:before {
    content: " #{'\f104'}";
}
```

and try adding this to the top of your scss file:

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

Source: 
[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1663)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am trying to fix the file-watcher so that this issue doesn't happen at all. Since I am downloading the font-awesome-scss-files every now and then to keep them update it would be a lot of work to do this manually. I just need to figure out why until a few days ago everything worked and now it does this. I just don't get it. But thank you any ways.

Comment: Have you specified an @charset at the top of your file?

Comment: No. Do you mean within the scss files?

Comment: At the top of your scss, please put ```@charset "utf-8";```

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. That did it. Would you like to edit your answer so that I can mark it as most helpful? Thank you.